# CVS - ignore Thumbs.db on Windows

Tags: cvs

What I tried so far is making a file, '.cvsignore' in the root of my module and then for the contents of the file:

*.Thumbs.db

However when I do CVS update, it still accounts for Thumbs.db - I just want it completely ignored by *any* cvs operation - is that possible?

And I don't really prefer CVS but I'm stuck using it for a certain project which I have no say on, otherwise I'd go with Mercurial or Git.

Comment: shouldn't this be on stackoverflow instead of here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want cvs to ignore files named Thumbs.db, why do you tell it to ignore files named `something[dot]Thumbs.db`?

Simply add `Thumbs.db` to your `.cvsignore` and you're done.

EDIT:

There are several candidates for the location of the `.cvsignore` file:

1. In the directory where the Tumbs.db file is located. This will only help for that single directory.
2. In your home directory. This will then apply do anything you do with cvs no matter what repository you are using.
3. In your CVSROOT directory. This will apply to all modules that belong to this repository.

Comment: also make sure Thumbs.db aren't in the repo or .cvsignore will not help

Comment: Because that's the first thing I tried, and I just realized that either
A) .cvsignore applies to the current directory in which it's in or
B) I need an advanced pattern so Thumbs.db can be ignored recursively throughout any subdirectory within my module.

Comment: I added some suggestions as to where to place the .cvsignore file to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't ignore, i go to my C drive, search the entire thing for Thumbs.db and delete them all :D

Comment: What's this system32 thing doing on my hard drive!

Comment: :D linux FTW..
Phoshi? from lifehacker? is that you?